# How to set text color

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which shows a text value. How can I set the color of the text to white?

```
class mphTickCounter {
map(d, i, history) {
const coordinates = {};
const cd = this.chartDescription
if (cd.underlyingType == "Tick") {
    const newValue = 
        d.value() === this.lastValue ? d.value() + this.contractInfo.tickSize : d.value()
    this.lastValue = d.value()

    const maxTicks = cd.elementSize
    const remainingTicks = maxTicks - d.ticks()
    const text = remainingTicks > 0 ? remainingTicks.toString() : ""

    return { 
        ticks: {
            text: ["", text],
            x: [d.timestamp(), d.timestamp()],
            y: [d.low(), d.high()],
        },
        value: newValue,
    };
} else {
    return {};
}
```

}

Comment: Please add context. What kind of framework, what `d` is etc.

Comment: You already asked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61776848/how-to-set-color-of-text And did again without changing nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set color of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61776848/how-to-set-color-of-text)